# Jenkins Logs stuck in <Server started in RUNNING mode> line, while running startWebLogic.sh

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to use Jenkins to perform Weblogic restart of Admin and manually servers. So i used **Execute Shell** option in the Build section to run 
**startWebLogic.sh** for starting the Admin server but the logs gets stuck after *`<Server started in RUNNING mode>`* line and next Unix commands are not executed.

I tried to use a function in shell to come out this condition, something like

```
function check()
{
key="<Server started in RUNNING mode>"
##kill the process after grepping the key 
done
}
```

It works fine while executing the shell form Linux box, but when invoked from Jenkins, it still gets stuck in `<Server started in RUNNING mode>` line.

I tried using `nohup` while invoking the `startWebLogic.sh` but Jenkins log is still getting stuck in below line

```
<Nov 30, 2017 4:02:56 AM PST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <Server started in RUNNING mode>
```

Need a way out, please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect output to some other log file, so that script will skip and execute next command.

**nohup sh start weblogic.sh &  > /tmp/logfile.out**

Comment: apologies for the delay in response, I have used `nohup`, but as I have mentioned it works fine if I execute the shell in Linux box. When I invoke the same shell using Jenkins, the logs get stuck in `<Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <Server started in RUNNING mode>`